# performing table merges outside of oracle in R

Tags: r, oracle

If I have a set of tables that I need to extract from an Oracle server, is it always more efficient to join the tables within Oracle and have the system return the joined table, or are there cases where it would be more efficient to return two tables into R (or python) and merge them within R/Python locally?

For this discussion, let's presume that the two servers are equivalent and both have similar access to the storage systems.

Comment: Oracle will be more computationally efficient - that is one of the main things it is built for.

Comment: Yes, that is what I believe too, but I'm wondering if there are any benchmarks that test the efficiency of table joins in R vs Oracle for example.   Or in what cases it would be more efficient to perform this externally.

Comment: In most use cases---as your question indicates---the SQL code would execute on a server and the R/python would run locally. In such a case it's not clear to me what "fair" benchmark comparison would be since usually the goal is to execute the code on identical hardware. R may be faster on your souped-up desktop than SQL on my 20-year-old server, but this isn't a helpful result. So do we compare a "typical" laptop to a "typical" database server, whatever that is?

Comment: Also, SQL isn't limited to data that can fit in memory, whereas any standard R packages are. So there's a clear case where SQL just wins.

Comment: I updated the question to include a comment that I'd like to consider the case where the two servers are equivalent (let's say they are both linux systems with equivalent memory and CPU and access to the same network storage.  In that case, is there still a clear benefit to doing the joins within Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I will not go into the efficiencies of joining itself but anytime you are moving data from a database into R kep the size into account. If the dataset after joining will be much smaller (maybe after an inner join) it might be best to join in db. If the data is going to expand significantly after join (say cross join) then joining it after extraction might be better. If there is not much difference then my preference would be to join in db as it can be better optimized. In fact if the data is already in db try to do as much of data preprocessing before extracting it out.